# What does "the cause of humanity" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I'm working on practice questions for SAT and there is a phrase whose meaning I can't figure out, namely "the cause of humanity". Here is the paragraph that is quoted in the SAT book:

> A recent major rabies epizootic that occured among raccons in the mid-Atlantix and north-eastern United States illustrates that even a zoonosis of antiquity can reassert its prominence in the modern era as a challenge for humans and wildlife alike. Throughout history, zoonoses also have been the **cause of humanity** at local, regional, and global level.

I'm wondering whether maybe the quote was shortened in a way that it lost its meaning. It is from Milton Friend, "Why Bother About Wildlife Disease?". You can find it here, on page 48 of the PDF and page 38 of the document: https://pubs.usgs.gov/circ/1401/pdf/circ1401.pdf
The sentence is not exactly the same in the original text.

Comment: The quote is completely wrong. "Throughout history, zoonoses also have been the cause of great “plagues” that have challenged the very existence
of humanity at local, regional, and global levels."

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's based on a misquote.

Comment: @DoneWithThis. this is what I thought, but I was also wondering if maybe I'm missing something and "cause of humanity" is a valid expression. Thank you

Comment: It is in and of itself a valid expression - but not one that belongs in this sentence. It's like walking along the pavement then stepping off a kerb without having seen it first; very jarring & throws your train of thought completely.

Comment: I think it's a mistake for _the curse of humanity_ .

Comment: I gave you an upvote because you included the source material for the quote and explained why you wondered whether the phrase was correct. Because the answer is simply "the practice question was misprinted", I think it would be best to close this question. That is just because of how the site works though, and not because I think it was a bad question.

Comment: I think the problem is [like the stepping unknowingly off a kerb] your first thought is that 'zoonoses made humanity possible'… it takes a serious mental rejig to side-shift to '[the study of] zoonoses is an aim/objective/purpose of humanity', as in 'a just cause' not a 'cause of illness'. That pavement comes right up to meet you, hard.